# Alinhamento do Text ao Input

Tags: html, css, input, label, scss

Boa noite pessoal, espero que estejam todos bem.

Estou tendo dificuldade em alinhar o Text em cima do Input.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group2 col-md-4">
              <label for="inputState">Estado</label>
              <select id="inputState"
              type="text"
              class="form-control">
```

**CSS**

```
#inputState {
padding: auto;
margin: 78px;
margin-top: auto;
width: 245px;
```

Uma imagem amostra sobre o que estou querendo fazer

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Ficaria muito grato se alguém pudesse me ajudar, e desde já peço desculpas caso perguntas assim forem
"comuns"**

**OBS:** Código com gambiarra talvez, não julguem, ninguém nasce sabendo. =D

Comment: Está usando bootstrap?

Comment: Estou sim bro :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, o que deseja são dois input fields lado a lado na mesma linha.
Utilizei o bootstrap 4. Você pode remover o css adicionado. Pois o bootstrap já trata o tipo de alinhamento que deseja.

Segue um exemplo de como fazer o alinhamento desejado:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>HTML5</title>
  <meta name="description" content="HTML5">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputState">Estado</label>
          <select id="inputState" type="text" class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Endereco</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rua número e bairro">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pra mim não deu certo :(

Comment: Conseguiu executar este exemplo?

Comment: Sim, mas ainda sim não alinha da forma correta :/, acho que vou refazer todo o HTML mesmo..